# Getting Missing member exception on vb.net windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Getting missing member exception was unhandled

```
Dim objDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("KMMiddleTier.xml")
    Dim el = objDoc.Descendants("ConnectionKeys").Descendants("ConnectionKey").Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("Key").Value = "DB_DEVQCE").[Select](Function(x) x)
    Dim result = el.Attributes("ConnectionString").FirstOrDefault().Value
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting option strict on?

Comment: It's off but i tried to ON and debug but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by "Option Infer"  -> ON